# Is there a plane curve of degree $d$ with more than $d^2$ rational points?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ of degree $d>3$ , irreducible and smooth(for its projective closure). The Mordell conjecture states that $f(x,y)=0$ has finitely many solutions. I wonder if there is an example where the number of solutions is larger than $d^2$?

The example with the greatest number of solutions that I can find is something like

$$\prod_{n=1}^d(y-n^2)-\prod_{n=1}^d(x-n)=0.$$

(Here, I include the $y-n^2$ terms to make the function irreducible.) I believe it may be the case that this equation has exactly $d^2$ rational solutions.

Comment: This isn't quite true as stated - you'll need to somehow include the condition that $f$ defines a curve of positive genus, else you can get things like $f=x^3+xy^3+y^5$ which has a rational parametrization by $(t^2(-1-t)^3,t(-1-t)^2)$ and hence infinitely many rational points.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, of course $f$ should be smooth. I forgot to add this condition, thanks.

Comment: Smooth isn't quite enough, you really do need the higher genus assumption: $V(y-x^n)$, for instance.

Comment: @KReiser $V(y-x^2)$ doesn't look to be smooth at infinity (if we projectivize it). Maybe we need to say smooth and projective to avoid hiding the singular point at infinity?

Comment: @daruma again, this isn't quite the right fix: there are polynomials which determine (affine patches of) curves which are singular at infinity but the Mordell conjecture still holds true for them. The real condition that fulfills the conjecture here is that the genus is at least 2, and that's what one should assume. (Trying to come up with the right combination of conditions on degrees, smoothness, etc. is exhausting and limiting. Just say the real condition - genus $\geq 2$!)

Comment: @KReiser But for projective smooth plane curves, $d>3$ is equivalent to $g>2$ right?

Comment: Right, but the original statement in this post was looking at an affine version. I'll stop trying to help now.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for pointing it out, and I edited the statement 1 hour ago.